# Add alternate text to hyperlink control from codebehind

Tags: c#, hyperlink, accessibility, alt

I am creating clickable images from the codebehind file as needed based on feedback from a web service.  I create the hyperlink using the hyperlink() method

```
HyperLink hyplAlertbox = new HyperLink();
```

then add the image to that using the "imageUrl" property

```
hyplAlertbox.ImageUrl = "~/templateimages/alert_scale_1.jpg";
```

This works, but the image contains no alternate text, which is an accessibility issue.  Is there a way to add alternate text from the code behind, or will I need to resort to javascript?

thanks

Comment: .Text works perfect.  sorry, I don't see a way to mark this as the "answer".  please let me know if I can.   thanks!

Comment: I set it up as an answer for you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set up alternative text for a `HyperLink` control, you can use the following:

```
HyperLink hyplAlertbox = new HyperLink();
hyplAlertbox.ImageUrl = "~/templateimages/alert_scale_1.jpg";
hyplAlertbox.Text = "Your alt text";
```

Just be sure that your `.Text` comes *after* you set the `ImageUrl`.